# ROT13 and upside-down text (flip text)

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation, text

How can we transform text in order to achieve [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) and [flip text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_of_text#Upside-down_text) using Wolfram Mathematica?

### 1. ROT13

[image]

### 2. Flip text

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### 1. ROT13

```
rotN[str_String, n_Integer: 13] := Module[
  {
   rule = Flatten@Normal[
      AssociationThread[#, RotateRight[#, n]] & /@ {
        CharacterRange["a", "z"],
        CharacterRange["A", "Z"]
        }
      ]
   }
  , StringReplace[str, rule]
  ]
```

Example

```
rotN["Mathematica Stackexchange, Zngurzngvpn Fgnpxrkpunatr"]
```

> "Zngurzngvpn Fgnpxrkpunatr, Mathematica Stackexchange"

### 2. Flip text

```
flipText[str_String] := Module[
  {
   rule = Normal@AssociationThread[
      Characters[
       "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥıɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz˙'"],
      Characters[
       "ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥıɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz˙'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,"]
      ]
   },
  StringReplace[StringReverse[ToLowerCase[str]], rule]
  ]
```

Example

```
flipText["Mathematica Stackexchange"]
```

> "ǝƃuɐɥɔxǝʞɔɐʇs ɐɔıʇɐɯǝɥʇɐɯ"

Comment: What alphabet / charset did you pull the flip text from, or is it from something external to Mathematica? (Just found that `CharacterName["ʍ"]` gives `"LatinSmallLetterTurnedW"`)

Comment: they are built-in eg `FromCharacterCode[607]` is upside down "f" ..

Comment: @george2079 I know. I was wondering if there was a built-in translation table, though.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I used text from [text-filter.com](http://www.text-filter.com/flip-rotate-text-twitter-facebook-blogs-forums.htm). The rules are not simple, see at the [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_of_text#Upside-down_text)

Comment: Here's an alternative rot13 only (no flip) that works w/ lowercase alphanumeric hashes: `rot13LowerAlphanumeric[
   str_] := (CharacterRange["a", "z"]~ Join~ 
        CharacterRange["0", "9"]) // 
      Query[{Identity, RotateRight[#, 13]&}] // 
     Apply[AssociationThread] // Normal // 
   StringReplace[str, #]&;`

Answer (score 6):

keeping it simple the rotation can be done just like this:

```
Rotate[#, Pi] &@"Hello World"
Rotate[Text[Style[#, FontSize -> 30]], Pi] &@"Hello World"
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As a follow up on a comment I made, here's a way I *tried* to convert from an arbitrary character to a flipped equivalent (which can maybe be extended by someone more knowledgeable about the subject). Unfortunately it isn't so simple to do.

First pull in the base unicode table and write a function that tries to find the version with / without `"TURNED"`, to use as the flipped variant:

```
If[! StringQ@$unicodeText,
  $unicodeText :=
   $unicodeText = 
    Import["ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt", 
     "Text"]
  ];
If[! AssociationQ@$unicodeTable,
  $unicodeTable :=
   $unicodeTable =
    First@# -> Rest@# & /@ 
      StringSplit[StringSplit[$unicodeText, "\n"], ";"] // 
     Association
  ];

unicodeNameSelect[name_] :=
  Select[$unicodeTable,
   StringMatchQ[First@#, name] &
   ];
unicodeLongFlip[charName_] :=

  With[{chunks = StringSplit[charName]},
   If[MemberQ[chunks, "TURNED"],
    unicodeNameSelect[StringRiffle@DeleteCases[chunks, "TURNED"]],
    Select[
     unicodeNameSelect[
      StringExpression @@ Riffle[chunks, " TURNED " | " "]],
     First@# =!= charName &
     ]
    ]
   ];
unicodeFlip[char : _String | _Integer] :=
 Replace[
  FromCharacterCode@FromDigits[#, 16] & /@ 
   Keys@unicodeLongFlip@CharacterName[char, "UnicodeName"], {
   {f_} :> f,
   {} -> None
   }]
```

Then we'll write something that tries to flip based on this (but with caching):

```
If[! AssociationQ@$flipEncoding, $flipEncoding = <||>];
flipEncode[char_String?(StringLength[#] == 1 &)] :=

  Lookup[$flipEncoding, char,
   $flipEncoding[char] =
    $flipEncoding[First@ToCharacterCode@char] =
     unicodeFlip[char]
   ];
flipEncode[char_Integer] :=
  Lookup[$flipEncoding, char,
   $flipEncoding[char] =
    $flipEncoding[FromCharacterCode@char] =
     unicodeFlip[char]
   ];
flipEncode[string : {(_String | _Integer) ..}] :=

  Replace[flipEncode[#], None :> "_"] & /@ string;
flipEncode[string_String] :=

 flipEncode[ToCharacterCode@string] // StringJoin
```

Then try to convert the alphabet:

```
In[181]:= flipEncode@StringJoin@{ToUpperCase@Alphabet[], Alphabet[]}

Out[181]= "Ɐ______Ɥ__ꞰꞀƜ______Ʇ_Ʌ____ɐ___ǝ_ᵷɥᴉ_ʞꞁɯ____ɹ_ʇ_ʌʍ_ʎ_"
```

And we'll see we have an atrocious success rate. That's largely because it seems most flips just use a different Latin character.

Plus there are some weird missing characters [like turned capital k](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a7b0/index.htm):

```
In[191]:= $unicodeTable["A7B0"]

Out[191]= {"LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED K", "Lu", "0", "L", "", "", \
"", "", "N", "", "", "", "029E"}
```